# I need help applying onFocus attribute to all elements of a class

Tags: javascript

My goal is to apply onFocus = "if(this.blur)this.blur()"; to all the area sections under an image map for a Microsoft Chart Control being dynamically created on the page.

Below, I go into IE and edited the 'attributes' field. This is achieving my desired goal, but I can't seem to get it in javascript.

I thought it should be this:

```
$(".area").onFocus(
    function () {
        if ($(this).blur) $(this).blur();
    }
)
```

but I do not see the same results when using this script. Any thoughts?

Cheers

EDIT:

I am now using the code:

```
$(".area").focus(
    function () {
        if ($(this).blur) $(this).blur();
    }
)
```

but this does not seem to replicate the same functionality as editing the attribute directly. Does anyone have an idea as to why? I can try using a more broad css selector, but as far as I can tell.. this should work!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
$(".area").focus(
    function () {
        if ($(this).blur) $(this).blur();
    }
)
```

UPDATE: For attribute edition:

```
    function focus_event() {
        if ($(this).blur) $(this).blur();
    }

$(".area").attr("focus", "focus_event()");
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your response. While this does not generate any errors on the page, it does not seem to replicate the same functionality as editing the attribute directly. The bug I am trying to patch still exists when I use this, but not when I edit the attribute directly...?

Comment: Added some code to edit the attribute, though it's not considered a proper way to do so...

Comment: Yep. Saw it, playing with it now. Still seeing the same results, just trying to get an alert to pop-up on focus right now.

Comment: If you're trying to block the `focus` event, you could try `return false`. Just a guess, it works with other events; not sure if you can "cancel" the focus.

Comment: I think I know where to go for now. Thank you!! :)

Answer (score 1):

You need `$('.area').focus(function() {...` not `onFocus`. [jQuery focus](http://api.jquery.com/focus/)

Comment: no idea. Just up-voted you, as I believe your answer is perfectly adequate to solve the OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

OK, you have a few problems. You're not closing the jQuery function with a ";". You're missing an "!" from before the if statement: "if (**!**$(this).blur())". Try this:

```
$(".area").focus(
    function () {
        if (!$(this).blur) $(this).blur();
    }
);
```

Comment: You don't need to terminate the jQuery event with a semi-colon. the if $(this).blur is checking to see if it is defined. It would be erroneous to try and call the event if it was not defined (which is what the bang is doing).